# Handling validation in MVC3 - one checkbox must be selected per checkbox group

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

[Title should say "one checkbox must be selected per question", but SO doesn't allow the word 'question' in the title]

Simple Q/A form. On one example, there are 7 questions. On POST, my controller action expects an `IEnumerable<AssessmentQuestionsModel>`. My `AssessmentQuestionsModel` implements `IValidatableObject`, and my Validate method is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (this.assessmentAnswers.Where(e => e.userAnswer == true).Count() == 0)
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult("You must select at least one answer for every question");
        yield break;
    }
}
```

This is working fine at the view level - it's returning that error message and displaying it in the validation summary. The problem is, it returns it 7 times, one for each of the questions. For now I'm using jQuery to evaluate the validation summary UL & remove duplicates, but that seems like a hack. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

[EDIT - testing validationresult overload]

The following is, in fact, called twice. However, they are not grouped, and multiple validation errors are still displayed.

```
if (this.assessmentAnswers.Where(e => e.UserAnswer== true).Count() == 0)
{
    yield return new ValidationResult("You must select at least one answer for every question", new List<string>() { "NoAnswerMarked" });
    yield break;
}
```

[EDIT - View Info]

```
@using System.Linq
@using System.Collections.Generic
@model IList<Academy.AssessmentQuestionsModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TakeAssessment";
    ViewBag.PageID = "TakeAssessment";
}
@section TitleBar {
    <span>
    @if(ViewBag.Status == "questions") {    
        <text>Take Assessment</text>
    } else {
        <text>Assessment Response</text>
    }
    </span>
}
@section JS {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if ($(".validation-summary-errors li:contains('You must select at least one answer for every question')").length > 0) {
            $(".validation-summary-errors ul")
                .find("li:contains('You must select at least one answer for every question')")
                .remove()
                .end()
                .append("<li>You must select at least one answer for every question</li>");
        }
        $("#asubmit").click(function (e) {
            var hasErrors = false;
            $(".newAnswerWrapper").each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:visible:checked').length == 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    hasErrors = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (hasErrors) {
                $(".validation-summary-valid").find("ul").append("<li>You must select at least one answer for every question</li>").end().show();
            } else {
                $(".validation-summary-errors").find("li:contains('You must select at least one answer for every question'')").remove().end().hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    <div class="takeAssessment">
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.AssessmentInstructions)) {
        <h4>Instructions</h4>
        <p>@ViewBag.AssessmentInstructions</p>
    }
    @{
    int questionCount = 0;
    int totalQuestions = Model.Count();

    @Html.Hidden("ModuleID", (int)ViewBag.ModuleID)
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].questionDescription)
            <div class="newQuestionWrapper">
                    <h4>Question @(i + 1) of @totalQuestions</h4>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].assessmentID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].assessmentQuestionID)
                    <p class="questionDescription">@Model[i].questionDescription</p>
                    <div class="newAnswerWrapper"></div>

                <div class="newAnswerWrapper">
                    <div class="answerHeader">
                        <p class="correct">Select</p><p class="answers">Answer(s)</p>
                    </div>

                 @for (var j = 0; j < Model[i].assessmentAnswers.Count(); j++)
                 {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].assessmentAnswers[j].assessmentAnswerID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].assessmentAnswers[j].assessmentQuestionID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].assessmentAnswers[j].assessmentAnswer)

                     if (ViewBag.Status == "questions")
                     {          
                         <div class="answerRow">
                            <span class="isAnswer first">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].assessmentAnswers[j].userAnswer)</span>
                            <span class="answerDisplay">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].assessmentAnswers[j].assessmentAnswer)</span>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].assessmentAnswers[j].isAnswer)
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                         </div>
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        <div class="answerRow">
                            @{
                                string cls = Model[i].assessmentAnswers[j].isAnswer ? "correct" : "incorrect";
                            }
                            <span class="isAnswer first">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].assessmentAnswers[j].userAnswer, new { @disabled = "disabled" })</span>
                            <span class="answerDisplay" style="width: 510px !important;">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].assessmentAnswers[j].assessmentAnswer)</span>
                            <span class="isAnswer"><span class="@cls">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].assessmentAnswers[j].isAnswer)</span></span>

                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                     }
                     <div class="clear"></div>
                 }

              </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
    }
}

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    @if (ViewBag.Status == "questions")
    {
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Assessment" class="redButton197x38" />
    }
</fieldset>
}
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Module", "Learn", new { id = ViewBag.ModuleID }, new { @class = "redButton197x38" })
</p>
```

Comment: Could you add your view information here please?

Comment: In the interim, you said you are removing duplicates through jQuery - you could also do this in your controller in the ModelState object

Comment: Testing your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I Have been thinking about your problem and I think the issue is alot simpler than what I was thinking, there is an overloaded constructor of the ValidationResult class where it asks to pass in the member names, if you pass in the same key( new List(){ "QuestionError" }) )here it should group them and only show the one result.